# Long Passwords: How are they more secure?

Tags: passwords, password-management, password-policy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XKCD #936: Short complex password, or long dictionary passphrase?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase)

How are long passwords more secure? The only situation in which I can accept long passwords are more secure is when someone is literally standing behind you, seeing what you are typing.

When it comes to someone using a Keylogger or Sniffer, the password length doesn't matters at all, your password will get compromised no matter what. Yet, at a lot of places I read/hear that long passwords are more secure. How?

Can someone mention some other situations in which long password will not get compromised whereas smaller will?

Comment: Makes a dictionary attack take longer.

Answer (score 5):

**Short Answer**

Long, complex passwords make you less susceptible to [brute-force attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack). Each time you add either an additional character set (e.g. a-z, A-Z, 0-9, special symbols, etc.) or increase the character length of your password, you're exponentially increasing the total number of possibly correct passwords (i.e. [the bits of entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29)), and that means it will take longer for a brute force program to guess the right one.

Note that for this to work ***the password must be both long and complex***. The password "123456789" is nine total characters, but will likely be guessed within the first dozen or so attempts.

Comment: Also, hackers usually skip symbols when brute-force cracking passwords, because it would take too long and few people use them, except maybe for the common !@.

Answer (score 2):

If a database full of hashed passwords is compromised, the hashes for the shorter passwords are much more vulnerable to brute-force cracking. And if it's not salted, then anything up at about 14 characters is likely to be in a rainbow table and thus very vulnerable.

Comment: Exactly, the longer the password, the longer it takes to brute-force it because the number of hashes to generate increases with every letter. Dictionary attacks are different, if there is a 15 letter word in a dictionary, then using that word for a password is as secure as using "123456" (not secure at all).

Comment: Even if it's salted, modern GPU cracking can achieve almost 50 billion MD5 hashes per second using off-the-shelf hardware. For a 10 character random alphanumeric password, that's an average cracking time of 10 hours. For 11 characters, it's 15 days. The only solution is a slow, tweakable hash algorithm like bcrypt or PBKDF2.

Comment: And for 16 characters, it's two and a half million years, using your own assumption of a times 36 increase in difficulty with an extra character. In practice, of course, that means it lasts until better hardware comes along, but well-chosen passwords of 16 characters or more are still effectively uncrackable.

Comment: I dont know the exact number of available characters or things about hashed or salted, but isnt it the following calculation kind of true (depending on set parameters); 26 characters in the alphabet x2 make 52, +10 numbers, +10 (not sure) other symbols make 72 possible characters. So a password of 9 without restrictions to what to use could in theory be one of 72^9 versions? Actual will be lower because of common restrictions and requirements?